# Where to store application settings

Tags: c#

I am creating an app that reads some info from a scale via RS232 serial port connection.  There are a couple of types of scales that are in use, so I would like to store specific settings for the scale in my program.  What is the best way to do this?  Via app.config?  Or should I put the values in a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

app.config would be the easiest option for you. I think a database might be a bit overdoing it for just some settings, but if you wish to use something outside of what is offered by VS (namely app.config) then you could always whip up a quick custom XML settings file.  All depends on what you wanna do with it and how comfortable you are with the other technology.

Answer (score 5):

It really depends on `where will these configurations be used?`

If you are working on a distributed huge system, which means these configurations are probably shared/used by other systems. You'd better store it in the database, with a common protocol which other related systems agree with.

On the other hand, if these configurations are used for a small application, storing them in a config file(or an xml file whatever you like) is suggested because, you don't need a gun in order to kill a mosquito.

Answer (score 1):

Is the information chaging ? that means when you ran ur app , would it be the case that information is updated ?

if the information is static and do not change frequetly , you can store in the app.config.

or in a xml file and you can read that information lately.

but if the information is dynamic then you need to create a model and expose scale information through model's peroperty.

Comment: That is actually not true.  I find it much simpler to do a quick edit to XML data using LINQ (when the amount of information is not too much) than to mess with a database.  But then again, that is a matter of personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Do not forget the registry.

Use the registry when:

- You need your settings to be accessible for a domain admin
- you need to secure some settings (using Windows security)
  (You can make some settings read-only)
- There are a lot of small settings that change very often

Comment: I disagree with your last point.  Just cause the settings are small and change often is not a good reason to add them to the registry.  That looks to me more like a reason to put them in a settings file.

Comment: If you store a lot of small settings in a .config, .xml (or old .ini) file, this will need a rewrite (and generation) of the whole file, for every small data change. The registry is optimized for this kind of actions.

Comment: From my understanding the whole point of a settings file is to store the small settings for the file that can be changed to affect run time or will be changed during run time and need to be saved for the next time the program is run.  Also if every program that you write dumps all of its settings into the registry then the users registry will become overly bloated rather quick (since the vast majority of programs don't clean their junk out when uninstalled)

Comment: The rationale for using the registry given here is quite valid.  Just not applicable to this specific question.

Answer (score 0):

If it's simple and straightforward than app.config is the way to go - you don't need to set up a database and you get to use simple built-in interfaces.

If you choose to go with a database check out mysql for a simple file based database that has a simple deployment scheme.